# Dynamic UPDATE fails due to unwanted parenthesis around string in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, update, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Using PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on Mac OSX 10.9.2 with Postgres.app.

I want to apply a function to all columns in a table, specifically I want to `trim` white space. So far I've got this in a file `test.sql`: (ed. fixed code after answer below)

```
do $$
declare
target text;
begin
    for target in
        select quote_ident(column_name)
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'cds' and data_type = 'character varying'
    loop
        RAISE NOTICE 'Calling trim(%)', target;
        execute 'update cds set '
            || quote_ident(target)
            || ' = trim('
            || quote_ident(target)
            || ')';
    end loop;
end
$$;
```

The `select` gives my a nice list of all the column names in my table and I was hoping to `for`-loop through all of those:

```
gakera=# select column_name from information_schema.columns
         where table_name = 'cds' and data_type = 'character varying';

 column_name 
-------------
 userID
 junk1
 dates
 times
 junk2
 junk3
 servID
 junk4
 junk5
```

### Sidetrack

Not the question, but just extra confusing.

The fun starts at `\i ~/path/test.sql` with this error:

```
psql:/path/test.sql:18: NOTICE:  Calling trim((anum))
psql:/path/test.sql:18: ERROR:  function quote_ident(record) does not exist
LINE 2:    || quote_ident(target)
              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.
       You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What's going on with `quote_ident`? I'm gonna try a sanity check, I copied this from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html

```
gakera=# select quote_ident('test');
 quote_ident 
-------------
 test
```

Ok, insanity check then:

```
gakera=# select quote_indeed('test');
ERROR:  function quote_indeed(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select quote_indeed('test');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.
       You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Ugh, whatever, I'll just remove the `quote_ident`function from the offending lines (it didn't complain about the `select quote_ident` part so I keep that. Now I have:

```
    execute 'update cds set '
        || target
        || ' = trim('
        || target
        || ')';
```

### Question

Here is where things start to get interesting. when I run this like before I get:

```
psql:/path/test.sql:18: NOTICE:  Calling trim((anum))
psql:/path/test.sql:18: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "trim"
LINE 1: update cds set (anum) = trim((anum))
                                 ^
QUERY:  update cds set (anum) = trim((anum))
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at EXECUTE statement
```

Why is it adding `()` around `anum`? How can I get rid of them? The `EXECUTE` statement should read `update cds set anum = trim(anum)`

Comment: Well I'm even dumber than I thought, since what I was trying to do is trim whitespace from just a few columns at once, this general method is complete overkill, I could have just updated multiple columns at once: `update cds set col1=trim(col1), col2=trim(col2), ... ;`. Maybe the general method above can help someone with a lot of columns, hopefully.

Comment: There is even shorter syntax for updating multiple columns: `update cds set (col1, col2, ...) = (trim(col1), trim(col2), ...)` Also simplifies dynamic concatenation of the SQL string - I make use of this in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first listed function is almost correct. Variable target should be of type `text`. Try this:

```
do $$
declare
    target text;
begin
    for target in
        select column_name
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'cds' and data_type = 'character varying'
    loop
        RAISE NOTICE 'Calling trim(%)', target;
        execute 'update cds set '
            || target
            || ' = trim('
            || target
            || ')';
    end loop;
end
$$;
```

Comment: omfg I can't believe it was that simple! It seems to be working now, thanks!

Comment: wait, so the `quote_ident` error was just a roundabout way of saying "function quote_ident not defined for variable type record"? I guess reading the error now I get it, but it could be clearer... `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` - I might no such thing!

Comment: You probably overlooked `ERROR:  function quote_ident(record) does not exist`.

Comment: Yea, I guess, at least I didn't connect it to the variable type. I'm still getting used to having to declare them explicitly, I've been spoiled by lazy languages in the past. As I said, I'm trying my best not to be a dumbass, but so far ... well ...

Answer (score 3):

[@klin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65223/3684) already addressed the bug you had been asking about. I am going to address your general approach.

Your `DO` statement would run a separate `UPDATE` for every column - which is almost *n* times as expensive as updating *n* columns at once.
Due to [PostgreSQL's MVCC model](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) this also produces *n* dead tuples in the table, leading to excessive table bloat and a lot of work for `VACUUM`.

What's worse, it updates every row n times even if nothing changes at all.

I suggest a *much* more efficient approach:

- Update every row *once*.
- Only update if anything actually changes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_trim_cols(IN _tbl regclass, OUT row_ct integer
                                                       , OUT col_ct integer)
  RETURNS record AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT format('
      UPDATE %s SET (%2$s) = (trim(%3$s))
      WHERE (%2$s) IS DISTINCT FROM (trim(%3$s))' -- test if anything changes
                , _tbl
                , string_agg (quote_ident(attname), ', ')
                , string_agg (quote_ident(attname), '), trim(')
                )
        , count(*)::int  -- count columns
   INTO   _sql, col_ct
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
   AND    atttypid IN ('text'::regtype, 'varchar'::regtype) -- basic string types
   AND    NOT attisdropped 
   AND    attnum > 0;

   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  --  debug
   EXECUTE _sql;  GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_trim_cols(regclass) IS 'Trim all columns of table _tbl ($1).
Return count of applicable columns (col_ct) and rows actually changed (row_ct) .
Call:
   SELECT * FROM f_trim_cols($$city$$)   --';
```

Produces SQL code like:

```
 UPDATE city SET (city, country) = (trim(city), trim(country))
 WHERE (city, country) IS DISTINCT FROM (trim(city), trim(country));
```

I also target `text` as well as `varchar` columns.
Everything is sanitized and safe against SQL injection.
More explanation, links and a fiddle in this related answer on SO:

- [Update multiple columns that start with a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344161/updating-multiple-columns-that-start-with-a-specific-string/16349111#16349111)