# Change column type from varchar to text in all tables at once

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I am using Postgres. I would like to change column type in all tables where column name is "description" from varchar(255) to text.

If anyone knows that I would be very glad for your help.

Comment: All tables in all schemas except system catalogs? Or all tables in a specific schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `DO` statement to run a single dynamic command:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN

RAISE NOTICE '%', (
-- EXECUTE (
   SELECT string_agg(format('ALTER TABLE %s ALTER COLUMN %I TYPE text'
                           , a.attrelid::regclass, a.attname), E';\n')
   FROM   pg_attribute a
   JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.oid = a.attrelid
   JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
   WHERE  a.attname = 'description'
   AND    a.atttypid = 'varchar'::regtype
   AND    NOT a.attisdropped                      -- no dropped columns
   AND    a.attnum > 0                            -- no system columns (redundant check)
   AND    format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) = 'character varying(255)'
   AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE ALL ('{pg_%, information_schema}'::text[])
   );

END
$do$;
```

Since the command is potentially hazardous I commented the `EXECUTE` and put a `RAISE NOTICE` there instead. After confirming the commands are sane, switch the comment characters `--` to actually execute the DDL commands.

[The manual on `format_type()`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)

This changes the type for *all* columns `description varchar(255)`, except for those in system catalogs, temporary tables (both starting with 'pg_') and the information schema. I build command from the system catalogs. [@a_horse demonstrates the other good option](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66394/3684) to use the information schema instead.

In your particular case, there can only be *one* column per table. **If** there can be multiple, it would be substantially cheaper to execute all type changes in a *single* `ALTER TABLE` statement per table. Commands of the form:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ALTER COLUMN col1 TYPE text
  , ALTER COLUMN col2 TYPE text
  , ALTER COLUMN col3 TYPE text;
```

More details in this related answer:
[Dynamic UPDATE fails due to unwanted parenthesis around string in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65221/dynamic-update-fails-due-to-unwanted-parenthesis-around-string-in-plpgsql/65229#65229)

Answer (score 8):

I guess you don't want to manually run all the necessary `ALTER TABLE` statements.

You can use the following statement to generate the needed `ALTER TABLE` statements:

```
select 'alter table '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' alter column '||column_name||' type text;'
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public'
  and column_name = 'description'
  and data_type = 'character varying'
  and character_maximum_length = 255;
```

replace `'public'` with your schema if your tables are not located in the `public` schema.

Run the above statement, spool the output into a text file, then run the generated script.

Something like this:

```
psql (9.3.4)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=> \t
Showing only tuples.
postgres=> \o alter.sql
postgres=> select 'alter table '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' alter column '||column_name||' type text;'
postgres-> from information_schema.columns
postgres-> where table_schema = 'public'
postgres->   and column_name = 'description'
postgres->   and data_type = 'character varying'
postgres->   and character_maximum_length = 255;
postgres=> \i alter.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ALTER TABLE / ALTER COLUMN feature.  A sample:

```
ALTER TABLE table_1
    ALTER COLUMN column_5 TYPE text,
    ALTER COLUMN column_10 TYPE text;
```

There is no global command to do this for you, but you could create a script to create all the ALTER TABLE / ALTER COLUMN commands and then run the script on your server.

Having said that, why do you want to change all of the 'description' columns to unlimited size? If a description should only be 100 characters (for example) it would be better to stick to a definition VARCHAR(100) that identifies what the limit should be.

Comment: @dezso Got it. I can see that as a rule of thumb `varchar(255)` is probably `varchar(max)`.  But having the intent of the data (e.g. one line on a report) control the data size is another useful rule of thumb.