# Can I add a primary key automatically for all tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database (postgresql) with 10 schema and every schema has 10 tables. For some reasons, some tables do not have a primary key.

Is it possible to create a function/trigger that can look for all tables and

- add a column `id_pk serial` (if the column does not exist)
- and make it a primary key (if the table has not any primary key)?

Comment: Postgresql has INFORMATION_SCHEMA catalog. It contains a view called `tables`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-tables.html Use it to get a list of tables. Another view, called table_constraints will give you a list of all constraints for the tables. Using these you will be able to build a dynamic SQL statements to generate keys

Comment: Yep, and you can use PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE` with the `format` function to generate an appropriate `ALTER TABLE ... ADD PRIMARY KEY ...` for each.

Comment: If a table doesn't have a PK, a person understanding the design should make a conscious decision about adding one or not. An artificial ID that would never going be used by any query is worthless and worse than that, a useless drag on write performance and a threat to previously-working code.

Comment: This related question has some answers demonstrating how to automate: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66387/change-column-type-from-varchar-to-text-in-all-tables-at-once