# Trigger function check if all NEW.* fields exist in another table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, plpgsql

In PostgreSQL I need to code a trigger function that checks if all the fields in `NEW.*` exist in another table that has the exact same name as the table that fired the trigger but appended with "_hv".

For example, if the table `my_example` fires the trigger I need to check if all the fields in `my_example` exist in `my_example_hv`, and if it does not, alter `my_example_hv` to add the fields that are missing.

I am very new to plpgsql and I starting trying to code it with no success:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_hv()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
    typeoffield character varying;      
BEGIN

FOR field IN NEW LOOP
      IF NEW.field not exists ON TG_TABLE_NAME||'_hv' THEN
        typeoffield := typeof(NEW.columns); -- of course does not work
        EXECUTE 'ALTER '||TG_RELNAME||'_hv ADD COLUMN '||NEW.column ||' '||typeoffield; 
      END IF;
END LOOP;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I think I need some expert help ...

Comment: So `my_example_hv` can have fewer columns. Can there also be extra columns and would that matter? Also, your version of Postgres, please. And please clarify a few things: the title asks to check for existence, while you go on talking about adding columns, which is something different. Also, what does your *trigger* look like? It find it hard to imagine a useful application for this trigger function. Since the trigger has to be created for a specific table, the trigger would be done and useless after the first invocation. Or are there other forces constantly dropping columns from your tables?

Comment: my_example_hv will have 4 more fields at the end when hv table is created, beacuse it is an exact copy of my_example plus four more fields, but if I insert new fields in my_example, imagine 6 new fields, those new fields need to be added to my_example_hv too... Postgresql version is 8.4 (I know its obsolete but I have some old software that needs that version).

Comment: I have insert, update and delte triggers that dill the my_example_hv with the modifications being made to my_example_hv. I use it to have a historic with all the changes being made in the table, so that later on, I can perfectly load an exact picture of what was at certain date. My issue comes when new fields are added to my_example table, those new fields need to be added too to my_example_hv.

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt fails for multiple reasons. First of all a *row* is not an *array*. This construct is just not possible:

```
FOR field IN NEW LOOP ...
```

But there is more.

I am not sure I like the general idea. This kind of trigger would run for at least every statement (don't use a row-level trigger for this!), which is quite a bit of overhead. It is also error-prone to put DDL commands in a trigger. Especially if you are a beginner.

That said, here is a proof of concept:

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_hv()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql
         'ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(TG_RELNAME || '_hv') || ' ADD COLUMN '
       || string_agg(quote_ident(attname) || ' ' || att_type, ', ADD COLUMN ')
   FROM  (
      SELECT attname, format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS att_type
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = TG_TABLE_NAME::regclass
      AND    NOT attisdropped   -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    attnum > 0         -- no system columns
      ) a
   LEFT   JOIN (
      SELECT attname
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = (TG_TABLE_NAME || '_hv')::regclass
      AND    NOT attisdropped
      AND    attnum > 0
      ) b USING (attname)  -- ignoring data type!
   WHERE  b.attname IS NULL;

   IF _sql IS NOT NULL THEN
      EXECUTE _sql;
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_foo_hv
BEFORE INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_hv();
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/17ad5/1)

This is a basic proof of concept. It does not check for matching data types and ignores things like schema `search_path`, `NOT NULL` constraints or `COLLATION`.

Related (with more explanation and links):

- [Change column type from varchar to text in all tables at once](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66387/change-column-type-from-varchar-to-text-in-all-tables-at-once/66402#66402)
- [Update multiple columns in a trigger function in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351196/939860)
- [Select rows where value of second column is not present in first column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16650/help-with-this-select-in-the-same-table/16651#16651)