# PostgreSQL GRANT ALL on mutliple tables using LIKE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, permissions, ddl, dynamic-sql

I have more than 100 tables named public.test_*

How can I easily `GRANT ALL` access to the user test to all that tables at once?

I tried with:

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.test_* TO test;
```

But it is not working ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GRANT` doesn't take wildcards in table identifiers.

You can use `ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA`, but that requires a single schema name.

If you want to do things with wildcard pattern table names you will need to use PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE format(...)` in a `DO` block to loop over the `information_schema.tables` view. See many related answers here on DBA.se and Stack Overflow for dynamic DDL in PL/PgSQL.

Untested rough example to give you the idea:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    t record;
BEGIN
    FOR t IN 
    SELECT table_schema, table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name LIKE 'test\_%'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('GRANT ALL ON TABLE %I.%I TO test;', t.table_schema, t.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For what `%I` means see the reference for the `format` function. If you don't have a `format` function your PostgreSQL is obsolete and you should probably plan an upgrade; you can use `quote_ident` and string concatenation in the mean time.

Answer (score 6):

What [@Craig already explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104176/3684).
Plus, since [**`GRANT`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html) can grant privileges on multiple objects at once, you can use a single statement without looping:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'GRANT ALL ON TABLE '
       || string_agg (format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), ',')
       || ' TO test'
   FROM   information_schema.tables
   WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
   AND    table_name LIKE 'test\_%'
   );
END
$$;
```

Related:

- [Change column type from varchar to text in all tables at once](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66387/change-column-type-from-varchar-to-text-in-all-tables-at-once/66402#66402)

Answer (score 1):

For postgresql 11 and later, the [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-grant.html) statement can take a comma separated list of objects of the same type as the grant targets, as [Erwin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104195/142621) points out. What's left is the creation of the list of objects you need.

For me, awk's easier to used for what Erwin manages quite elegantly with PL/pgSQL:

```
psql DBNAME -c '\dt ${TABLE_PATTERN}*' | awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{s="";t=""} /^\s*public/{gsub(/ /, "", $2); t=t s $2; if(!s){s=","}} END{print t}'
```

The above comma seperated list can then be used as the input directly (via copy/paste) or via parameter replacement by piping through `xargs`.

***Note**: I understand this is not a pure DBA answer, but there are definite instances of this kind of task falling under the devops umbrella (which is how I came to this question).*