# Revoke privileges for a user on tables with like names

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Attempting to adapt this [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104172/postgresql-grant-all-on-mutliple-tables-using-like), but for revoking privileges in this way:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    t record;
BEGIN
    FOR t IN
        SELECT table_schema, table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
        AND table_name LIKE 'test\_%'
        LOOP
            EXECUTE format('REVOKE DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE ON TABLE %I.%I FROM test;', table_schema, table_name);
        END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, I'm getting "column table_schema does not exist". Am I approaching this the right way?

Using postgresql 9.6 (french locale).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the record of the cursor loop:

```
EXECUTE format('REVOKE DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE ON TABLE %I.%I FROM test;', 
               t.table_schema, t.table_name);
               ^-- here        ^-- here
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `psql` and run

```
SELECT format(
          'REVOKE DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE ON TABLE %I.%I FROM test;',
          table_schema,
          table_name
       )
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
AND table_name LIKE 'test\_%' \gexec
```